# Network theorem Source Transformation

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

When i am using Superposition Theorem i am getting 80W but when i using Source transformation getting 0W.Why getting different answers?

Is there anything Hidden in source transformation that I need to know.

[image: Circuit Discription]

I am sure about applying Superposition Theorem. For Source transformation I am converting both current source in voltage source with resistor in series. After that I am applying KVL that gives me zero current. Am I doing something wrong? 
I am new in circuit Analysis.
Please Guide

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you used superposition and did source transformation for this problem? In one of those you got the wrong answer, but we can't tell what you did wrong if we don't know what you did at all.

Comment: @Felthry I am sure about applying  Superposition Theorem. For Source transformation I am converting both  current source  in voltage source with  resistor in series. After that I am applying KVL that gives me zero current. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you performing source transformation on the resistor you're trying to measure power in? Zero current is correct, but that only applies to the resistors you don't touch in your source transformation, i.e. the 10Ω one.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work. How did you do the source transformation withou eliminating the 5 ohm resistor?

Comment: I think you proceeded by finding current in 5 ohm resistor after transforming 5ohm + current source into a voltage source. That 's wrong calculations.

Comment: I guess I got my answer I need not to touch the 5ohm resistor as i am calculating power dissipation in it. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, yes.

Comment: Right, It's not the same resistor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used source transformation to transform the combination of current source and parallel resistor in the left side and the right side into voltage sources, then you can find current, power and voltage **only** in the components which are external to the sources.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSb0Hl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here its only 10 ohms resistor. Calculations on 5 ohm resistor or 4 ohm resistor which are part of the sources, will yield you wrong results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your explanation. Suppose I want to calculate power dissipation in 5ohm using Source Transformation only how can I proceed?

Comment: Not useful. If 5 ohms is the concern, tranform only the source on right side. Left side should be left alone and use superposition theorem .

Comment: Thanks Leis. Actually I am new in circuit analysis and I m making lot of error while solving problems.I know I need lot of practice. Can you please suggest me a good book or website having lot of problems.

Comment: I use one book by Theraja and schaum's outline series.

Comment: http://eng.harran.edu.tr/~msuzer/files/edt/edt.pdf : Good one

Answer (score 0):

If you take a step back and ask yourself what the voltages will be on the 2 top nodes if the 10 k resistor is removed, you will see that on both nodes, the voltage is 20 volts. If you added any value resistor in place of the 10 k clearly there is no voltage across it so zero current flows through it hence the 5 ohm resistor has 20 volts across it and dissipates 80 watts.

It's just a sanity check.

Comment: Now I have a bit understanding of source Transformation. Thanks @Andy for your Answer.